# Phase space 3D diagram

Tags: plotting, nonlinear, initialization

I want to draw a diagram for nonlinear dynamic system in three dimensions $(m,y,A)$ but I don't know how do it.
These are my equations:

```
y'[t] == 2 (y[t] - 1)*(3 y[t] - 5 m[t]) + 4 A[t]* m[t]* (y[t] - 1), 

m'[t] == 3 m[t]*(y[t] - 1) - 5 (m[t]^2)*(y[t]^(-1))*(3 y[t]/2 - 1) + 
  2 A[t]*(m[t]^2)*(y[t]^(-1))*(2 y[t] - 1) + m[t]*(3 y[t]/2 - m[t]) 

A'[t] == A[t]*m[t]
```

Comment: It would help if you defined what you meant by a "diagram".

Answer (score 4):

How about a vectorfield and a time-trajectory? Is it what you are expecting?

```
ode = {
   y'[t] == 2 (y[t] - 1)*(3 y[t] - 5 m[t]) + 4 A[t]*m[t]*(y[t] - 1), 
   m'[t] == 
    3 m[t]*(y[t] - 1) - 5 (m[t]^2)*(y[t]^(-1))*(3 y[t]/2 - 1) + 
     2 A[t]*(m[t]^2)*(y[t]^(-1))*(2 y[t] - 1) + m[t]*(3 y[t]/2 - m[t]),
   A'[t] == A[t]*m[t]
   };

time = 100;
sol = NDSolve[Join[ode, {y[0]==.1, m[0]==.1, A[0]==.1}], {y, m, A}, {t, 0, time}];

Show[
 VectorPlot3D[Last /@ ode /. (x_[t] :> x),
     {y, .05, .2}, {m, .05, .2}, {A, .05, .2}],
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{y[t], m[t], A[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, time}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]